# Padding of container is ignored if anchor link is used

Tags: html, css, overflow, anchor, padding

I have a container with overflow set to hidden, and it has a child which is higher than it. When I activate an anchor link to an object inside of it, container's padding-top is no longer used in calculating it's children's position.

How do I keep padding-top intact?

HTML:

```
<a href='#target'>Hit the top</a>
<div class='container'>
  <div class='tall'>Tall object</div>
  <div id='target'>Target</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
  padding: 40px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.tall {
  position: absolute;
  left: 200px;
  height: 2000px;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/aSDk5/2/

I've tested it (on Win7) in IE, FF, Chrome, Opera, Safari and the results are the same.

Comment: That's because of absolute positioning of the div with class "tall". Try setting margin-top instead?

Comment: Here, have a look at this fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/55mJS/

Comment: Margin-top won't solve this issue - the task is to keep all children elements to be positioned as they were relative to container.

Comment: Ohkay. Hashem's solution seems good.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, there's nothing wrong with the `padding`. It's working.

The fact is when you hit the hyperlink, the content of `container` scrolls up to the top of the `#target` element.

And the above space (which you see that as `padding-top` visually), would be hidden because of `overflow: hidden;` CSS declaration.

You can check the padding by using `overflow-y: scroll;`.

```css
.container {
    background-color: navy;
    padding: 40px;
    position: relative;
    overflow-y: scroll; /* Then, move the scroll-bar to check the padding */
}
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/aSDk5/4/)**.

Answer (score 2):

The scroll-margin-top property lets you define a top margin that the browser should use when snapping a scrolled element into place.
For example using scroll-margin-top: 10vh; will jump to the anchored section but 10vh higher, exactly what you want.